# Mac Snow Leopard Server DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, osx-snow-leopard

I have a Tomcat-driven application on my Windows server that I am planning to move to a MacMiniServer.  Before I do this, I want to fully test the transition for licensing purposes.

I have a Fire drive setup with Snow Leopard Server and the base app runs just fine BUT I need to be able to resolve the URL to my domain and not localhost.  So, I figured I would setup panomedia.net in the DNS Server and also create an A record to my internal network IP so www.panomedia.net would dish out the same thing as localhost.

The problem is:

1. The Tomcat web app starts up going through panomedia.local and not through www.panomedia.net and
2. My main network preference panel is still looking at my Comcast DNS search providers even though I put my local IP address as the only DNS Server and Search provider.

I need to test this via an actual domain name before I commit to a 400GB data move.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Concerning the DNS looking at Comcast.. is it receiving an IP address via DHCP? Is the DHCP server instructed to assign the comcast DNS server?

Answer (score 1):

you can add domain names to /etc/hosts 
add the entry :
127.0.0.1 www.panomedia.net